# How do I remove the space caused by commas separating a variable and string (Python 2.7.5)

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm new to python, I've only been using it for about 5 months but I'm ambitious and am currently working on a project to help me in the long run in terms of GCSEs.

```
print PercentComplete, "% complete"
```

I want to remove the space so instead of it printing "6.66 % complete", it would print "6.66% complete"

Many thanks
Miles

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print without newline or space?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493386/how-to-print-without-newline-or-space)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do `print str(PercentComplete)+"% complete"`

In your answer, you were printing two different things. Here you combine it into one item and print it

Comment: Thanks. It works like a charm! I'll mark this as the best answer because it was the one that made the most sense to me! :D

Answer (score 2):

Use [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) - it's much more flexible and robust. In this case:

```
print "{}% complete".format(PercentComplete)
```

Answer (score 0):

A common way to do it is using string format.

```
print('%.2f %% complete' % PercentComplete)
```

This way you always will have the number correctly formatted.

The output will be

```
6.66% complete
```